# How to find the boundaries of groups of contiguous sequential numbers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with the following definition

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
  (
     id     INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     number BIGINT,
     status INT
  )
```

and example data

```
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES (100,0),
       (101,0),
       (102,0),
       (103,0),
       (104,1),
       (105,1),
       (106,0),
       (107,0),
       (1014,0),
       (1015,0),
       (1016,1),
       (1017,0)
```

Looking only at the rows where `status = 0` how can I collapse the `Number` values into ranges of contiguous sequential numbers and find the start and end of each range?

i.e. For the example data the results would be

```
         FROM      to 
Number    100      103
Number    106      107
Number    1014     1015
Number    1017     1017
```

Comment: I've done this before, months ago. I don't think I saved the query, but it might still be in my local logs. Hold tight.

Comment: google for "sql server gaps and islands"

Comment: sorry i can't find it.

Comment: Oh wow there's an entire tag on SO for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands

Comment: SQL is very inefficient at looking at data across rows without a cursor (and cursors are bad!).  I strongly recommend you coming up with a way to either store the ranges in another collection, or pull down all the data and crunch the numbers (i.e. calculate the ranges) yourself.  With that said, you can likely get away with using a recursive CTE to get the job done.  How exactly, I'm not sure.  As suggested, check out gaps and islands.

Comment: come on genius, I know u can find the solution ;)

Comment: @EliGassert This is entirely untrue. "Gaps and Islands" problems can be solved very efficiently in SQL with resorting to either Cursors or the even more iniefficient Recursive CTEs. Itzak Ben-Gan has written extensively on how this can be done. Here: http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/calculating-concurrent-sessions-part-3

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments this is a classic gaps and islands problem.

A solution [popularized by Itzik Ben Gan](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/calculating-concurrent-sessions-part-3) is to use the fact that `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY number) - number` remains constant within an "island" and cannot appear in multiple islands.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY number) - number AS Grp,
                number
         FROM   mytable
         WHERE  status = 0)
SELECT MIN(number) AS [From],
       MAX(number) AS [To]
FROM   T
GROUP  BY Grp
ORDER  BY MIN(number);
```

On later versions my preference is to use `LAG`/`LEAD` for this to reduce the amount of sorting going on. The below should work from 2012+

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       MinNumber  = MIN(number) OVER (ORDER BY number ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
       NextNumber = LEAD(number) OVER (ORDER BY number)
FROM mytable
WHERE status = 0
)
SELECT LAG(NextNumber, 1, MinNumber) OVER (ORDER BY number) AS [From], 
       number AS [To]
FROM T
WHERE NextNumber IS NULL OR NextNumber <> number+ 1
```

Comment: +1: Yes, this is the best approach.  No cursed Cursors or inefficent recursion necessary.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Very modest! Apologies for crediting the wrong person in my answer!

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, my one claim to fame. :-)  Besides, Itzak Ben-Gan really is a genius IMHO.

Comment: why did you user the - in your query ?

Comment: @MikeStation - As opposed to what? The `GRP` value needs to be something constant within an island and unique to an island that achieves it. e.g. See the results here and experiment with changing the example data and you should see how it works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1040/2