# Find a hole in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that contains basic information about instruments.  Each instrument has in instrument id (000000-999999), that is its unique identifier.  There are some holes in the instrument ids that i need to find.  Is there a SQL query I can write to find where there are gaps in the instrument id column?  It would be really helpful if I could find the largest holes (with the most instruments missing).  I've searched around for an answer to this but it seems like most solutions involve two tables with a join, where this instance is only on 1 table.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The Martin Smith link worked perfectly.  For anyone else who may want to use it, remove "WHERE  status = 0" from the query if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a start:

```
;
WITH    Instrument  AS
(       SELECT  Id
        FROM    ( VALUES
                ( 01 ),
                ( 02 ),
                ( 03 ),
                ( 05 ),
                ( 09 ),
                ( 10 ) ) AS Sample (Id)

),      Sequence AS
(       SELECT  MIN(Id) Start,
                MAX(Id) Finish
        FROM    Instrument
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  Start + 1,
                Finish
        FROM    Sequence
        WHERE   Start < Finish
)
SELECT      Sequence.Start
FROM        Sequence
LEFT JOIN   Instrument
        ON  Sequence.Start = Instrument.Id
WHERE       Instrument.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: I'd be nervous about how a recursive CTE and a self-anti-semi-join will perform against a table with hundreds of thousands of rows. I think [the `ROW_NUMBER()` solution in the proposed duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17046749/61305) will scale a lot better.

Comment: I would probably use a tally table with a left join onto the data table.  Any nulls where ID in the data table is match is your holes in your data.  Very simple to understand instead of recursion.